# Unexpected exception parsing XML document in applicationContext-security.xml

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have this error while I run my web application in eclipse:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

In some web pages I have seen that the conflics between spring and spring security makes this exception but
I have checked the library versions,all of them are 3.x
here is the classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="WebContent/WEB-INF"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre6">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="//10.60.2.7/Sabka/Salehnia/asvadi/lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="//10.60.2.7/Sabka/Salehnia/asvadi/lib/ojdbc14dms.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-runtime-3.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/freemarker-2.3.13.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-2.6.11.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/SpringWS/SpringStruts2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xwork-2.1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: You don't have _any_ Spring Security jars in this classpath file.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a Spring [3.1.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.html#getLocalName%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) or later. [3.0.0.M3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.html#getLocalName%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) does not contain the getLocalName method (javadocs linked).

I'm not sure what is trying to call that method though (perhaps you could paste more of the stack trace), but upgrading is the first thing to do.